# While Loops in MYSQL/PHPMyAdmin with Dates

Tags: mysql, date, while-loop, phpmyadmin

I am trying to pull a sum from my data that is comparing one month to the next. The below code provides what I need to compare two months but I need to run this over 4 years.

```
    SELECT as_of_date,  
    Sum(case when `as_of_date` = '2014-02-01' AND disclosure_number IN(
        SELECT disclosure_number 
        FROM `gnma_cohort`
        WHERE obp BETWEEN '125001' AND '150000' AND in_the_money BETWEEN '0' 
        AND '49.999' AND `as_of_date` = '2014-01-01') THEN 1 END) AS '2014-
        02-01'       
        FROM `gnma_cohort`
```

I am new to MySQL but from what I have read it seems a While loop would be my best option.  Below is my attempt at creating the loop but I keep getting errors on my delimiter, is this not the correct format for mysql in PHPMYAdmin? I also do not have the standard ; delimiter in my code that I have seen other examples use, but I never use the ; delimiter in phpmyadmin. Any advice on how to fix my code would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
     DELIMITER $$

     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS itmdates$$
     CREATE PROCEDURE itmdates()

     BEGIN
          DECLARE startdate DATE

          WHILE startdate < '2017-10-01' DO

                SELECT as_of_date,  
                Sum(case when `as_of_date` = startdate AND disclosure_number 
                IN(
                SELECT disclosure_number 
                FROM `gnma_cohort`
                WHERE obp BETWEEN '125001' AND '150000' AND in_the_money 
                BETWEEN '0' AND '49.999' AND `as_of_date` = 
                DATE_SUB(startdate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS 
                'startdate'

          SET startdate = DATE_ADD(startdate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

          END WHILE

          END$$
```

Comment: I'm nearly 100% certain this could be done with a single mysql statement. Generally running a sql statement inside a loop is considered a bad idea (unless you are iterating over objects like tables or columns). Can you share your table structure, some sample data, and your desired results?

Comment: The columns that I am currently dealing with are disclosure_number, as_of_date, obp, and itm.                                                                                                                   
I am trying to track all the loans from month 1 given certain conditions (obp and itm) that are still around in month 2.

Comment: My table structure is                                                      
disclosure_number int(10)                                                      obp decimal(11,2)                                                                
as_of_date  date                                                                                                 in_the_money decimal(5,3)